# Program to show the number of characters in a string

Tags: c

This is a program to find the number of characters in a string. But it counts the wrong number of  characters. Is it counting the white space too ? Even if that is true how can the total number be 89 ? (see output below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


void occurrence(char str[100], char ch)
{
 int count=0,max =0,i;
 for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
 {
   if(str[i]!='\0')
   {
     max = max + 1;

     if(str[i]==ch)
     {
      count = count + 1;
     }
   }
 }

 printf("\nTotal Number of characters : %d\n",max);
 printf("\nNumber of Occurrences of %c : %d\n",ch,count);
}

int main(void)
{
 void occurrence(char [], char);
 int chk;
 char str[100], ch, buffer;

 clrscr();
 printf("Enter a string : \n");
 gets(str);

 printf("Do you want to find the number of occurences \nof a particular character (Y = 1 / N = 0) ?  ");
 scanf("%d", &chk);

 do
 {
  if (chk==1)
  {
   buffer = getchar(); //dummy varaiable to catch input \n
   printf("Enter a Character : ");
   ch = getchar();
   occurrence(str,ch);
   printf("\n\nDo you want to check the number of occurences \nof another character (Y = 1 / N = 0) ? ");
   scanf("%d", &chk);
  }
  else
  {
   exit();
  }
 }
 while(chk);

 return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaaagh! Never use `gets()`! It is impossible to use safely by its very design. If your textbook suggested using `gets()`, burn it. If your teacher/prof suggested using `gets()`, drop the course. Seriously; this kind of thing is a sign of much worse nonsense to come...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, please explain why it is bad to use gets(). Is it bad to use them in C or it is bad to use them in other languages too ? . I wanted to read a number of characters including white space till I pressed "Return" button

Comment: To use **it**; `gets()` is a function. It's bad because, like I said, it is impossible to use safely by its very design. It says so in its documentation (see the 'bugs' section), and explains more about why. (If you don't understand the explanation, you need to study more.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two important things wrong with the `for` loop that counts characters:

1. It goes from 0 to 100, when it should go from 0 to 99. If you allocate a 100-element array, then the index of the highest element is 99, for a total of a hundred elements. Traditionally the exit condition for the loop would be `i < 100`, not `i <= 100`.
2. It keeps going after the '\0' is found. The '\0' character marks the end of the string, and you should not count any characters after it. Some of the characters after the '\0' may themselves be '\0's, and so you won't count them; but there could be any other kind of garbage there as well, and those will mess up your count. You must figure out how to change your `for` loop to exit as soon as the '\0' character is found, and not count anything else after that point.

Comment: ` for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
 {
   if(str[i]!='\0')
   { 
     max = max + 1;

     if(str[i]==ch)
     {
      count = count + 1;
     }
   }
   else
  {
   break;
  }
 }`

Comment: The `break` is a fine way to go, yes indeed. And the `<=99` will work, but honestly, it looks very n00by -- the '< 100' is much more idiomatic.

Comment: How to skip white space characters  ?

Comment: You'd have to check each character to see if it's whitespace. You could check individually for ' ',  '\t', '\f', '\n', '\r', etc, or you could use the C standard library routine `isspace(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whitespace is a character. Also are characters each of the 100 elements in your array. You are counting everything but nulls, sp I guess you have 11 nulls. Also, your for loop is off by one.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you correct output.

```
void occurrence(char str[100], char ch)
```

{
    int count=0,max = 0,i = 0;

```
while(str[i]!='\0')
{
    max = max + 1;

    if( str[i] == ch )
    {
    count = count + 1;
    }
    i++;
}
```

}